# Independence of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$, with $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Assume that $\sigma(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})$ is independent of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is independent of $\mathcal{C}$. Now I want to show that $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are independent, and so in particular $\mathcal{C}$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$.

Secondly, I am looking for a example illustrating that the independence of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ not necessarily follow from having $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ independent.

Of course we start with:

$\forall E \in \sigma(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$, $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\forall C \in \mathcal{C}$ we have that $P(A \cap E)=P(A)\cdot P(E)$ and  $P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. How to extend this information to find that:

$\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$, $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\forall C \in \mathcal{C}:$ $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C)$.

Comment: Check yourself, probably "we start with" $P(B \cap C)=P(B)\cdot P(C)$, not $P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ (the sets are from corresponding $\sigma$-algebras).

Comment: Counterexample you seek can be easily constructed from the example of three pairwise, but not mutually independent events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with what we want to prove. Let $A\in \mathcal{A}, ~B\in \mathcal{B}, ~C\in \mathcal{C}$ and we shall prove that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C).$ Since $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $~B\cap C\in \sigma(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})$ and $\mathcal{A},~\sigma(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C})$ are independent, we get $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B\cap C).$  Since $B \in \mathcal{B},~C\in \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{B},~\mathcal{C}$ are independent we get $P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$, as desired.